# Add the padding spaces back to CHAR after appending varchar string

Tags: sql, sql-server, char

I have a CHAR(250) field , which , for example will initially contain 10 byte data and 240 bytes of space, so remaining it has 250-10=240 bytes . Now I wanted to append a varchar of length say 20 bytes . So it will go to 240 + 20 =260 bytes which while inserting back to CHAR field will give size overflow issue.

Can do this , but I need the actual length , that means i want to re-pad the final string , ie 250 bytes in the final length ,

```
DECLARE @Var CHAR(250)='var lenght initial Data'
SELECT replace(@Var,' ','')
DECLARE @TempVar VARCHAR(20) = 'new text to be added'
SET @FinalVar=@Var + @TempVar
--Need to add final padding back to make it back to 250 bytes
```

Is there any other way rather counting and re-adding the space pads back ?

Comment: which database are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like there is no 'proper' fix to this but this is what I ended up with

```
DECLARE @Var CHAR(250)='var lenght initial Data'
SELECT @Var=replace(@Var,' ','')
DECLARE @TempVar VARCHAR(20) = 'new text to be added'
SET @FinalVar=@Var + @TempVar
SELECT @TempEmails= CAST(left(@FinalVar, 250) AS CHAR(250)) --CAST to char pads back to 250 , this is the easiest way
```

the Tweak is the `CAST AS CHAR(250)` which will re-pad the string to 250

Answer (score 0):

This is really your expected result?

The initial value all in the left, and the new values beeing added to the right?

[image]

Comment: "var length initial Data new text to be added<---------------spaces----------->" , Total length must be 250